# Select blocks delimited with 3 new-lines

Tags: regex, markdown

I have an existing regex (https://regexr.com/45gpv) which selects blocks separated by 2 new line charaters:

```
/^((?:[^\n]|\n(?! *\n))+)(?:\n *)+\n/gm
```

and I would like to change it to work with **3 new line** characters. I marked the desired behavior. (Single and double new lines should not be separators.)

```
lorem ipusm dolor ↵        ⎤ 
sit amet, consectetur. ↵   ⎦ 
↵                          
↵
adipiscing elit, ↵         ⎤
sed do eiusmod tempor ↵    ⎥
↵                          ⎥
incididunt ut labore ↵     ⎥
et dolore ↵                ⎥
magna aliqua. ↵            ⎦
↵
↵
ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco ⎤ 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.           ⎦
```

Can someone help me please editing the regex, I was not able to reshape.

I use the regex for [simple-markdown](https://github.com/Khan/simple-markdown) rule to implement a markdown -> html parser.

The actual rule looks like this with the old regex:

```
export const sectionRule = {
  order: SimpleMarkdown.defaultRules.paragraph.order - 0.5,
  match: blockRegex(/^((?:[^\n]|\n(?! *\n))+)(?:\n *)+\n/),
  parse: parseCaptureInline,
  react: (node, output, state) => <section>{output(node.content)}</section>,
};
```

Comment: Try `/^.+(?:\n{1,2}.+)*/gm` or `/^.+(?:\R{1,2}.+)*/gm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/^.+(?:\n{1,2}.+)*/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g9DN4f/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (due to `m` modifier)
- `.+` - 1 or more chars other than line break chars
- `(?:\n{1,2}.+)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `\n{1,2}` - 1 or 2 newlines
  - `.+` - 1 or more chars other than line break chars.

In some regex flavors, `.` may match any char other than LF, in some it matches any char other than any line break chars. To make the pattern "safer", just replace `.` with `[^\n]`: `/^[^\n]+(?:\n{1,2}[^\n]+)*/gm`.

If you have to adjust it to `\r\n` or `\n` or just `\r` endings use `/^[^\r\n]+(?:(?:\r\n?|\n){1,2}[^\r\n]+)*/gm`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. The separation works perfectly but I do not get back the content of the sections. I use the regex for simple-markdown rule (I completed my question with the details).

Comment: @gazdagergo Do you mean you need to have a capturing group? Wrap it all with parentheses, `/^(.+(?:\n{1,2}.+)*)/`. If multiline mode is default, do not use `m`. If global mode is default, no need using `g`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
/([\s\S]*?)(?:\R{3,}|\z)/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qEefGx/2/)

(Note: This only works if the three lines do not contain horizontal white space characters which you example has.)

Comment: Thanks @dawg. It works perfectly in your demo however I cannot get the desired behaviour in my exact use-case (I completed my question). Do you have an idea why? Thanks in advance.